# How to split large file by size without affecting last line in unix?

Tags: shell, unix, sh

For example, The source file is of 1 gb with 25000 lines, I want to split the files with size threshold 100 mb. I need the small files with whole lines and not with partial line in 1 file and remaining partial line in other file, because of size constraints. Thanks in advance. Please let me know if my question confuses.

Comment: Please use **GB** for gigabytes according to SI standards https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte and also **MB** for megabytes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte Also a small *b* denotes **bits** not **bytes** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabit so your *"100mb"* means 100 millibits.

Answer (score 2):

If your `split` command supports option `-C size` or `--line-bytes=size` (see `man split`) you can use

```
split -C 100M inputfile
```

Answer (score 2):

@bodo's `split -C` is a better solution, but if you don't have that, you can count the characters as you go with `awk` and roll over to a new output file whenever you get to 100*1024*1024 characters of output.

Note that there is an implicit assumption of 1 byte per character here - watch out if using multi-byte characters etc.

```
awk '{
   # Total up length of this line plus a line-feed
   t=t+length($0)+1
   # If we have reached 100MB, roll over the chunk number and zero tally
   if(t>100*1024*1024){c+=1;t=0}
   # Write current line to file "chunk-NNN.txt"
   print >> "chunk-" (c+1) ".txt"
}' YourFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's that simple:

On my PC, I have a file, called "prebuild.txt". In order to know the size, I do `ls -l` (this can be parsed):

```
Prompt>ls -s prebuild.txt
135868 prebuild.txt
```

So, the size is about 135,868 Mb.

The amount of lines can be found, using `wc -l`:

```
Prompt>wc -l prebuild.txt
424358 prebuild.txt
```

In order to cut it into a piece of ±100Mb, I need to know the percentage:

```
Prompt>$ echo 100*100000/135868 | bc
73.6
```

So, I need about 73.6% of the file. The corresponding amount of lines:

```
echo 73.6*424358/100 | bc
312327,488
```

Just putting the first 312327 lines of the file into file1.txt should do it:

```
head -312327 prebuild.txt >file1.txt
```

The rest can be done playing with `head` and `tail` on the reminding lines of the original file until nothing's left anymore.

P.s. I didn't test the `bc` related commands (I don't get bc, basic calculator, installed on my system).